# What is the SO rep-fraud policy?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, answers, serial-voting, plagiarism

What is the official way (if there is any) to deal with people who commit reputation fraud? With that I mean following behavior:

> Posting of abbreviated version of old answers, to gain reputation. Possibly involving 3rd party to up-vote them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Re-hashing of old answers requires attribution, in accordance with the CC:Wiki license used on Stack Overflow.  In other words, the poster must:

1. Credit the original author, and
2. Place the original text in a block quote.

Failure to do so gives the impression that the poster wrote the answer himself, and people do vote accordingly.

Copying other people's answers without attribution is a suspendable offense, and so is sock-puppeting.  Cast a moderator flag on one or more of the offending posts, with a custom description explaining the problem, and a moderator will take care of it.